# Python string replacement without expected ouput

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use FunkyPenguin's [RadarrSync](https://github.com/funkypenguin/RadarrSync/blob/master/RadarrSync.py) script, but I'm having trouble with some string replacement
I have tried to log it out, so I could see what was happening:

```
            path = movie['path']
            path_fr = ConfigSectionMap(server)['path_from']
            path_to = ConfigSectionMap(server)['path_to'] 
            logging.debug('path {0}'.format(path))
            logging.debug('pathto {0}'.format(path_to))
            logging.debug('pathfrom {0}'.format(path_fr))
            path2 = path.replace(path-fr, path_to)
            logging.debug('path2 {0}'.format(path2))
```

Gives me this result:

```
2020-04-30 16:19:35,409 [MainThread  ] [DEBUG]  path /mnt/unionfs/Plex/Film/Film/The Big Lebowski (1998)
2020-04-30 16:19:35,409 [MainThread  ] [DEBUG]  pathto '/mnt/unionfs/4K/'
2020-04-30 16:19:35,409 [MainThread  ] [DEBUG]  pathfrom '/mnt/unionfs/Plex/Film/Film/'
2020-04-30 16:19:35,409 [MainThread  ] [DEBUG]  path2 /mnt/unionfs/Plex/Film/Film/The Big Lebowski (1998)
```

I don't get why the path2 variable still shows the path.

Comment: is `path-fr` a typo ? When i change that to `path_fr` i get path2 showing as `/mnt/unionfs/4K/The Big Lebowski (1998)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both path_fr and path_to contain quoted strings. Thus path_fr is NOT a part of path.

```
path_fr = "'/mnt/unionfs/Plex/Film/Film/'"
```

Compare the output of:

```
print("'/mnt/unionfs/Plex/Film/Film/'")
print('/mnt/unionfs/Plex/Film/Film/')
```

Comment: Giant facepalm. Thank you